# Subtract from previous record - Nested query SQL

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a query like following :

```
select ISNULL(sum(fonhand),0.00) as 'Supply', 0 as 'Demand'
from invoice where ptno = @ptno 
union  
select distinct  a.quantity as 'Supply', 0 as 'Demand'
from jbMstr a join jbDetails b on a.fjobno = b.fjobno
  where a.ptno = @ptno AND a.status = 'RELEASED' AND fbmsource = 'S' 
union
select  0 as 'Supply',  ftotqty as 'Demand'
from jbDetails a join jbMstr b on a.fjobno = b.fjobno
where fbompart = @ptno and fstatus = 'RELEASED' AND fbmsource = 'S'
```

The output like following :

```
Supply    Demand       Avail
-4.00000 0.0000000000    -4
0.00000 1.0000000000     -5
0.00000 1.0000000000      -6
0.00000 4.0000000000      -10
0.00000 -1.0000000000     -9
```

Here i want to get new column "Avail" and it should be subtract from "Demand" column in each row. How can implement this?

Can anyone help me to do this?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (ISNULL() is a product specific function.)

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT since UNION removes all duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Use Running total trick to do this

Considering you have a column to identify the order

```
SELECT [supply], 
       [demand], 
       [avail] 
FROM   Yourtable a 
       CROSS apply(SELECT Sum(supply - demand) AS [Avail] 
                   FROM   Yourtable b 
                   WHERE  a.id >= b.id) cs
```

In `Sql Server 2012+` you can use `Sum() Over(Order by)` window function to calculate running total

```
SELECT [supply], 
       [demand], 
       Sum(supply - demand)OVER(ORDER BY id) as Avail, 
FROM   Yourtable
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. I tried with first one.. But it don't allow Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery...

Comment: Just a side note. SUM() Over works for 2008+ according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx). I have used it with 2008R2.

Comment: @KaviSuja - Are sure is this the query you executed because there is no aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery present in my query

Comment: @mxix - yeah we can use `sum() over()` but you cannot use `order by` inside the `over` clause in `sql server 2008`